# Angular Type Script Object log to console

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having some issues with assigning some values to an object in my component file. So i want to be able to see whats in the res.

i use the following on ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((res: any) => {
  console.log('House Info');
  console.log(res);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res);
  this.houseInfo = res.houseInfo;
});
```

}

I am getting in both cases

> { houseInfo : "[ object Object ]"}

So question is how can i get the actual content of the Object

Comment: Set a breakpoint in subscribe

Comment: OK, when you get that ` "[ object Object ]"` in console, what should it be instead? What is the actual URL in the bar?

Comment: It should _never_ be an object, by the way. It's a query parameter, it can only ever be string (even when it's number, it'll be represented as string and you need to explicitly parse it). How did that `[object Object]` get there?